# How to inherit from SQLAlchemy classes and own classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiple-inheritance

I have a problem with class inheritance using SQLAlchemy.

The following min. example shows what I'd like to do and what my problem is:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 'hello world'

class Car(Base, Foo):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = Column(String(50))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 'bar' attribute is available on new class instance
    my_car = Car()
    print my_car.bar # "hello world"

    # 'bar' attribute is not available on query init
    db_session = init_db()
    my_car = db_session.query(Car).first()
    print my_car.bar # Error
```

I have a `Car` class which inherits from SQLAlchemy's `Base` class. In addition to that the `Car` class inheritates from a `Foo` class. In This example the `Foo` class just consists of an attribute `bar`.

When a `Car` instance is instanciated via SQLAlchemy's query function I can't access the `bar` attribute. How is SQLAlchemy instantiating classes and is there a workaround for me?

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cls`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.cls) parameter to `declarative_base` to replace default `object` as base for all your classes:

```
Base = declarative_base(cls=MyBaseClass)
```

For more information and options, please read [Mixin and Custom Base Classes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes) section of documentation.

Comment: The documentation seems to have moved here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html